# Creating a BeautifulSoup object in a child thread will print a encoding error

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup, thread-safety, lxml

I wrote an example code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from threading import Thread
def test():
    r = requests.get('http://zhuanlan.sina.com.cn/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

print('run test on main thread')
test()

print('run test on child thread')
t = Thread(target=test)
t.start()
t.join()
```

the output is:

```
run test on main thread
run test on child thread
encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x95 0x50 0x22 0x20
encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x95 0x50 0x22 0x20
encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x95 0x50 0x22 0x20
```

I wrote a test function, and run it in main thread and a child thread. As is shown in the output, the test function run in child thread print `encoding error: input conversion failed due to input error` and I can't prevent it. why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue and wanted to build upon @real_kappa_guy's solution which is the correct idea but may require more explanation.

I believe error comes from BeautifulSoup's attempt to determine the document's encoding. It uses a library called "Unicode, Dammit" to detect the encoding, but often the document doesn't contain enough information to accurately determine the encoding. These cases are what can lead to the encoding error being printed out.

The fix is indeed to specify the `from_encoding` parameter with whatever the document's original encoding is (`iso-8859-1` is an example). You can get the encoding programmatically from the response:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml', from_encoding=r.encoding)
```

There's more information in BeautifulSoup's documentation [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this comes from the xml parser ... Because with an HTML parser the error disappears ...

```
def test():
    r = requests.get('http://zhuanlan.sina.com.cn/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

I obtained this:

```
run test on main thread
run test on child thread
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of late, but just incase anyone come across this again, this do the trick for me:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml',from_encoding="iso-8859-1")
```